# click event not listening in fullscreen in Chrome in macos

Tags: google-chrome

Why is the click event not being detected in fullscreen mode in Chrome on a system running the latest macOS Sonoma 14.0, while it works perfectly in windowed mode, and are there any known compatibility issues or potential solutions to address this problem?

Any assistance or guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated, as it seems to be a significant obstacle for the full functionality of the application on the latest macOS Sonoma 14.0 in Chrome's fullscreen mode. It's essential to find a solution to ensure a seamless user experience.